# firebase cannot Write user data

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i am trying to create a user with email and password  using fire-base, the user can successfully register but when i want to write user data it does not work. 
i suspect that there might be something wrong with my WriteUserData method.
this is a snippet of my code

```
firebase.initializeApp(config);
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
   if (user) {
     // User is signed in.
      window.location.href = 'home.html';
      var userId = user.uid;




   } else {
     // No user is signed in.
       alert("You Are not Logged In");
   }

 });



 $("#RegisterBtn").click(
   function(){
     var database = firebase.database();
     var name=$("#RegisterName").val();
     var email=$("#RegisterEmail").val();
     var password=$("#RegisterPassword").val();
     var cell=$("#RegisterCell").val();
     var rank=$("#RegisterRank").val();


        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {

            // Handle Errors here.
            $("#RegisterError").show().text(error.message);


            $("#RegisterBtn").show();






        });
        function writeUserData(userId, name, email, password,rank,cell) {
  firebase.database().ref('Administrators/' + userId).set({
    username: name,
    email: email,
    password : password,
    rank   : rank,
    cellphone:cell
  });
}
  });

  function isNumber(evt) {
    evt = (evt) ? evt : window.event;
    var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a very good debugging mechanism. Did you check your JavaScript console for errors? Did you step through the code?

Comment: You'll definitely want to handle errors when writing data. See http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase/5548/how-do-i-listen-for-errors-when-accessing-the-database/24459/detecting-errors-when-writing-a-value-in-javascript#t=201610290111514741298

Comment: i did try this code but still it doesn't work                                                                                                                                                                             var db = firebase.database().ref();
db.set("My new value").catch(function(error){
      console.error(error);
      alert("me");
  });

Comment: it also says set is not a function

Comment: You seem to be redirecting on sign-in via firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged. You check user is not null and then redirect. I don't see where you are writing your data. It could be that the observer is interrupting that logic.